# Need Your Help : MYSQL ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried to create a table, but I got

> MYSQL ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint

. Here's the code:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS `users`;
CREATE SCHEMA `users`;

USE `users`;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `useraccount`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `userinfo`;

CREATE TABLE `account` (
    `uid` BIGINT unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uname` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `passwd` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(`uid`)
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;

CREATE TABLE `info` (
    `uid` BIGINT unsigned ZeroFill NOT NULL,
    `rname` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    `phone` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `email` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `uid` (`uid`),
    CONSTRAINT `fkinfo` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `userAccount`(`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You dont have a table useraccount but account

Comment: You can't create a foreign key reference to table *useraccount* because you don't have one. Your table is named *account*. Voting to close because the issue is simply a misnamed table (a typographical mistake), and therefore the question will be of zero use to others in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any `userAccount` table.  Perhaps you intend the `Account` table:

```
CONSTRAINT `fkinfo` FOREIGN KEY (`uid`) REFERENCES `Account`(`uid`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4aa3) is a SQL Fiddle.